# permission for music files

Tags: java, android

I want to declare a permission to access all the music files from external storage 
Please tell me all the books steps to achieve this.

Comment: `Please tell me all the books steps to achieve this.` are you serious? are you really looking for a tutorial... **here**?!

Answer (score 0):

Try put this in your manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: do note that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is Protection level: dangerous. you will need to programmatically request for permission, besides updating the manifest. see https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: ok,i'm just a beginner and do not know that. Thank you for your advise

Answer (score 0):

Put the following permissions in manifest.xml file outside the application tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your manifest file first:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

External storage might be unavailable and that may cause the app to crash. So you need to check programmatically whether you have external storage available and if that storage is readable. The following code snippet will help to achieve the goals:

```
/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```